Bicep Error: The resource is not defined in the template
I am getting this weird issue in Bicep where when I try to deploy the security policy for Azure Front Door it works when custom domain is defined but when no custom domain is defined and trying to use the frontdoor endpoint it throws the below error. There seem to be some validation issue in trying to reference the FrontDoor when using the FrontDoor Endpoint Id to associate to the Security Policy.

"message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource
'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afd-test' is not defined in the template.
Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax for usage details.'."

main.bicep
module azureFrontDoor 'FrontDoorEndpoint.bicep' = {
  name: 'azureFrontDoor${frontDoorProfileName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(SharedResourceGroup)
  params: {
    frontDoorProfileName: frontDoorProfileName
    endpointName: frontDoorEndpointName
    wafRateLimitThreshold: wafRateLimitThreshold
  }
}

WafPolicy.bicep
param wafManagedRuleSets array = [
  {
    ruleSetType: 'Microsoft_DefaultRuleSet'
    ruleSetVersion: '2.1'
    ruleSetAction: 'Block'
  }
  {
    ruleSetType: 'Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet'
    ruleSetVersion: '1.0'
  }
]

var wafRateLimitRuleForDDoSCustomRuleSet = [
  {
    action: 'Block'
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
    matchConditions: [
      {
        matchValue: [
          '::/0'
        ]
        matchVariable: 'SocketAddr'
        negateCondition: false
        operator: 'IPMatch'
      }
    ]
    name: 'RateLimitRuleForDDoS'
    priority: 100
    rateLimitDurationInMinutes: 5
    rateLimitThreshold: wafRateLimitThreshold
    ruleType: 'RateLimitRule'
  }
]


resource wafPolicy 'Microsoft.Network/FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2022-05-01' = {
  name: wadPolicyName
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: skuName
  }
  properties: {
    policySettings: {
      enabledState: 'Enabled'
      mode: wafMode
    }
    managedRules: {
      managedRuleSets: wafManagedRuleSets
    }
    customRules: {
      rules: empty(wafCustomRuleSets) ? wafRateLimitRuleForDDoSCustomRuleSet : concat(wafRateLimitRuleForDDoSCustomRuleSet, wafCustomRuleSets)
    }
  }
}

output wafPolicyId string = wafPolicy.id

FrontDooEndpoint.bicep
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

resource wafPolicy 'Microsoft.Network/FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2022-05-01' existing = if (wafPolicyName != '') {
  name: wafPolicyName
  scope: resourceGroup(wafPolicyResourceGroup)
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = if(!empty(keyVaultName)) {
  name: keyVaultName
  scope: resourceGroup(keyVaultRG)
}

resource frontDoorEndpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2023-05-01' = {
  name: endpointName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope: 'SubscriptionReuse'
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}

module wafPolicyModule './WafPolicy.bicep' = if(empty(wafPolicyName)) {
  name: 'wafPolicy'
  params: {
    wadPolicyName: replace('WAF${endpointName}', '-', '')
    wafRateLimitThreshold: wafRateLimitThreshold
    skuName: skuName
    wafMode: wafMode
    wafCustomRuleSets: wafCustomRuleSets
  }
}

resource secret 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/secrets@2023-05-01' = if(!empty(customDomainName)) {
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: certificateName
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      type: 'CustomerCertificate'
      useLatestVersion: true
      secretSource: {
        id: '${keyVault.id}/secrets/${certificateName}'
      }
    }
  }
}

resource customDomain 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customDomains@2023-05-01' =  if(!empty(customDomainName)) {
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: replace(replace(customDomainName, '.', '-'), '-', '')
  properties: {
    hostName: customDomainName
    tlsSettings: {
      certificateType: 'CustomerCertificate'
      minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS12'
      secret: {
        id: secret.id
      }
    }
  }
}

resource securityPolicy 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/securityPolicies@2023-05-01' = {  
  name: replace('Security${endpointName}', '-', '')
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      type: 'WebApplicationFirewall'
      wafPolicy: {
        id: !empty(wafPolicyName) ? wafPolicy.id : wafPolicyModule.outputs.wafPolicyId
      }
      associations: [
        {
          domains: [
            {
              id: !empty(customDomainName) ? customDomain.id : frontDoorEndpoint.id
            }
          ]
          patternsToMatch: [
            '/*'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Issue seems to be with the way you frontDoorEndpoint retry by directly adding direct ID instead of the way you refered in the configuration @kolexinfos

is it coming from the module or the main template?

I guess its from main templete. It might be with the way refer frontdoorprofile name or missing scope reference in resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing

refer this image if the rg is different you need mention the relevent scope

@vinay How do you mean directly adding the ID, are you saying the frontdoorEndpoint.id is not the correct way to do it?

@VinayB I am already scoping the module to use the correct resourceGroup and it works when I create an Endpoint with Custom Domain and Certificate, I updated my post with the module reference from main template

so most parameters have empty value in your case?

@Thomas Yes, most of the values are empty for the case I see the error, which is for the scenario when no Custom Domain or TLS Certificate configuration is required.

Just curious, have you tried adding dependsOn: frontDoorEndpoint to the resource declaration of your securityPolicy?

@D1__1, the parent property will ensure the dependsOn.

could you share your wafpolicy module please? im trying to get a reproductible deployment.

@Thomas updated the post with the wafpolicy module

which type of FD are you using classic  / standard / premium ?

The main issues for this deployment are the empty "checks".
Even if you set a condition, the resource name can't be empty as ARM checks the number segments in the resource id.
This will throw an error:
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing = if (!empty(frontDoorProfileName)) {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

This won't
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing = if (!empty(frontDoorProfileName)) {
  name: !empty(frontDoorProfileName) ? frontDoorProfileName : 'notapplicable'
}

I created a CustomDomain.bicep module that is executed only when a custom domain is required:
param keyVaultRG string
param keyVaultName string
param frontDoorProfileName string
param customDomainName string
param certificateName string

// Return custom domain id
output id string = customDomain.id

// Get a reference to the existing front door
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

// Get a ference to existing key vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
  scope: resourceGroup(keyVaultRG)
}

// Create the secret 
resource secret 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/secrets@2023-05-01' = {
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: certificateName
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      type: 'CustomerCertificate'
      useLatestVersion: true
      secretSource: {
        id: '${keyVault.id}/secrets/${certificateName}'
      }
    }
  }
}

// Create the custom domain
resource customDomain 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customDomains@2023-05-01' = {
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  name: replace(replace(customDomainName, '.', '-'), '-', '')
  properties: {
    hostName: customDomainName
    tlsSettings: {
      certificateType: 'CustomerCertificate'
      minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS12'
      secret: {
        id: secret.id
      }
    }
  }
}

The FrontDoorEndpoint.bicep module then looks like this:
param frontDoorProfileName string
param wafPolicyName string = ''
param wafPolicyResourceGroup string = ''
param keyVaultName string = ''
param keyVaultRG string = ''
param endpointName string
param customDomainName string = ''
param certificateName string = ''
param wafRateLimitThreshold int
param skuName string = 'Premium_AzureFrontDoor'
param wafMode string = 'Detection'
param wafCustomRuleSets array = []

// Get a reference to the existing front door
resource frontDoorProfile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2023-05-01' existing = {
  name: frontDoorProfileName
}

// Create the endpoint
resource frontDoorEndpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2023-05-01' = {
  name: endpointName
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope: 'SubscriptionReuse'
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
  }
}

// If there is an existing waf, use it
resource wafPolicy 'Microsoft.Network/FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2022-05-01' existing = if (!empty(wafPolicyName)) {
  name: !empty(wafPolicyName) ? wafPolicyName : 'notapplicable'
  scope: resourceGroup(wafPolicyResourceGroup)
}

// Otherwise create a new/default one
module wafPolicyModule './WafPolicy.bicep' = if (empty(wafPolicyName)) {
  name: 'wafPolicy'
  params: {
    wadPolicyName: replace('WAF${endpointName}', '-', '')
    wafRateLimitThreshold: wafRateLimitThreshold
    skuName: skuName
    wafMode: wafMode
    wafCustomRuleSets: wafCustomRuleSets
  }
}

// Create a custom domain if required
var addCustomDomain = !empty(customDomainName) && !empty(certificateName) && !empty(keyVaultRG) && !empty(keyVaultName)
module customDomainModule './CustomDomain.bicep' = if (addCustomDomain) {
  name: 'CustomDomain'
  params: {
    frontDoorProfileName: frontDoorProfile.name
    keyVaultRG: keyVaultRG
    keyVaultName: keyVaultName
    certificateName: certificateName
    customDomainName: customDomainName
  }
}

// Create the security policy
resource securityPolicy 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/securityPolicies@2023-05-01' = {
  name: replace('Security${endpointName}', '-', '')
  parent: frontDoorProfile
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      type: 'WebApplicationFirewall'
      wafPolicy: {
        id: !empty(wafPolicyName) ? wafPolicy.id : wafPolicyModule.outputs.wafPolicyId
      }
      associations: [
        {
          domains: [
            {
              id: addCustomDomain ? customDomainModule.outputs.id : frontDoorEndpoint.id
            }
          ]
          patternsToMatch: [
            '/*'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Then from the maim deployment it is invoked like that:
param frontDoorProfileName string = 'fd-thomastest-001'
param SharedResourceGroup string = 'stackoverflow'
param frontDoorEndpointName string = 'fde-thomastest-001'
param wafRateLimitThreshold int = 1000

module azureFrontDoor 'FrontDoorEndpoint.bicep' = {
  name: 'azureFrontDoor${frontDoorProfileName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(SharedResourceGroup)
  params: {
    frontDoorProfileName: frontDoorProfileName
    endpointName: frontDoorEndpointName
    wafRateLimitThreshold: wafRateLimitThreshold
  }
}

